# What is the best way to recursively generate all binary strings of length n?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, language-agnostic, binary

I'm looking for a good (easy to implement, intuitive, etc.) **recursive** method of generating all binary strings of length `n`, where `1 <= n <= 35`.

I would appreciate ideas for a pseudo-code algorithm (no language-specific tricks).

LE: okay, I did go overboard with the upper limit. My intention was to avoid solutions that use the binary representation of a counter from `1` to `1 << n`.

Comment: Good luck for n = 100 :)

Comment: That would be 1267650600228229401496703205376 distinct strings for N=100 - ain't gonna happen in my life time.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of recursion in C++.

```cpp
vector<string> answer;

void getStrings( string s, int digitsLeft )
{
   if( digitsLeft == 0 ) // the length of string is n
      answer.push_back( s );
   else
   {
      getStrings( s + "0", digitsLeft - 1 );
      getStrings( s + "1", digitsLeft - 1 );
   }
}

getStrings( "", n ); // initial call
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Divide et Impera paradigm, the problem of generating all binary strings of length n can be splitted in two subproblems: the problem of printing all binary strings of lenght n-1 preceeded by a 0 and the one of printing all binary strings of lenght n-1 preceeded by a 1. So the following pseudocode solves the problem:

```
generateBinary(length, string)

if(length > 0)
    generateBinary(length-1, string + "0")
    generateBinary(length-1, string + "1")
else
    print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def genBins(n):
    """
       generate all the binary strings with n-length
    """
    max_int = '0b' + '1' * n
    for i in range(0, int(max_int, 2)+1, 1):
        yield str(format(i, 'b').zfill(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(list(genBins(5)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have can be solved with a [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.

**Pseudo-code** for such an algorithm is:

```
fun(input, n) 
    if( base_case(input, n) ) 
        //print result
    else
        //choose from pool of choices
        //explorer the rest of choices from what's left
        //unchoose
```

**Implementation:**

- Base case: we want to print our result string when its size is equal to **n**
- Recursive case:

  - our pool of choices consists of **0** and **1**
  - choosing in this case means take 0 or 1 and add it to the **input** as last character
  - explore by recursing, where we pass the new **input** value from the choose step until base case is reached
  - un-choosing in this case means remove the last character

```js
function binary(n) {
  binaryHelper('', n);
}

function binaryHelper(str, n) {
  if (str.length === n) {
    //base case
    console.log(str); //print string
  } else {
    for (let bit = 0; bit < 2; bit++) {
      str = str + bit; // choose
      binaryHelper(str, n); // explore
      str = str.slice(0, -1); // un-choose
    }
  }
}

console.log('Size 2 binary strings:');
binary(2);
console.log('Size 3 binary strings:');
binary(3);
```

You can re-write the code above like this, where you choose & un-choose by stateless transition from one loop iteration to another. This is less intuitive though.

```js
function binary(n) {
  binaryHelper('', n);
}

function binaryHelper(str, n) {
  if(str.length === n) {
    console.log(str);
  } else {
    for(let bit = 0; bit < 2; bit++) {
      binaryHelper(str+bit, n);
    }
  }
}

console.log('Size 2 binary strings:');
binary(2);
console.log('Size 3 binary strings:');
binary(3);
```